# How to create a multi-line UILabel, with a maximum width?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uilabel

I'm writing a simple IRC client that I'm modeling after Twitter's iOS app appearance. I've taken a screenshot of the Twitter app, for reference:

[image]

It looks like a simple table view with a few labels inside of each cell. So, in my app, I am programmatically creating a table and the cell formatting. My custom cell has only two labels in it, which I have positioned one on top of the other. The top label is a simple 1-liner. The bottom label I would like to contain longer messages, and need it to word-wrap to multiple lines while staying within my specified width.

How do I achieve this?

So far, I've tried explicitly setting the frame of the label to the dimensions that I want, but it does not word-wrap, if this is all I do. It just flows out of the cell horizontally. I then tried calling `sizeToFit`, within the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function, for this label, but it appears to word-wrap at a very small width - the text wraps after like two or three letters and then flows out of the cell vertically.

I can't seem to figure out how to get the text within the label to wrap after a specified width. Any ideas?

My custom cell class: https://github.com/ryancole/pound-client/blob/master/pound-client/views/MessageListCell.m

The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function: https://github.com/ryancole/pound-client/blob/master/pound-client/controllers/MessageListViewController.m#L62-L84

Edit 1:

To demonstrate what happened when I set `numberOfLines` to 0, for unlimited, I have attached a screenshots of that being called. It wraps after a few characters, instead of first taking up the specified width of the UILabel's frame. This is being set prior to called `sizeToFit`.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set numberOfLines to the number of lines you want, or 0 which allows for an unlimited number of lines (the default is 1). You might also need to set the lineBreakMode to  NSLineBreakByWordWrapping (although that might be the default).

**After Edit:** If you want the text to start at the top, then I think you'll have to use variable height cells, and not set an explicit size for your custom cell. I did it this way in one of my projects:

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.numberOfLines = 0; // allows label to have as many lines as needed
    label.text = _objects[indexPath.row][@"detail2"];
    CGSize labelSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 300000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGFloat h = labelSize.height;
    return h + 50;
}
```

The label I create here, is just for calculating the height of the row, it's discarded after this method ends. The width of the cell is determined by the 300 argument I have in the constrainedToSize: parameter. The +50 was just a fudge factor I added to get my cells looking right -- you'd probably want to mess with that number to get what you want. In my custom cell class, I used initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier, and didn't set any size.

Comment: I'd like it to take as many lines as it needs. I tried setting it to 0, to give it unlimited, but that's when it wrapped at like two or three characters, and did not take up the whole specified width. I'll update my original post with a screenshot illustrating this.

Comment: Don't call sizeToFit if that is what you are doing. You shouldn't have to do that. If you set numberOfLines to 0 it should wrap the words to the next line automatically assuming there is enough vertical space in the label to allow for the extra lines.

Comment: @Ryan, try removing the sizeToFit lines in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, and see if that helps. You're setting an explicit size in your init method, so I don't think you want those.

Comment: Oh, ok that did it! I was just combining `sizeToFit` with the explicit widths which now looking back at it seems like a bad idea. Thanks!

Comment: Although I now recall why I was using `sizeToFit` - I wanted to align the text within the label vertically at the top. Any idea how to do this without sizeToFit?

Comment: @Ryan, I don't know what you mean by align vertically at the top.

Comment: UILabel's appear to align the text within them in the center, vertically.

Comment: @Ryan, I think you have to use variable height rows to get what you want -- I edited my answer to show how I've done that.